# PDE's numerical integration: simplify output: get rid of $[t,r]$'s and ${}^{(0,1)}$'s

Tags: numerical-integration, simplifying-expressions, numerics, output-formatting, output

When numerically integrating PDE's systems mathematica output can be chaotic and therfore time-consuming or even impossible to understand and use.

A major source of confusion are the  $[t,r]$'s and ${}^{(0,1)}$'s that appear in standard mathematica output display.

I believe things would get better if $[t,r]$'s were omitted and  ${}^{(0,1)}$'s and ${}^{(1,0)}$'s were replaced by traditional $\partial_r$ and $\partial_t$ respectively.

So, for example, I used

```
Derivative[0, 1][B][t, r] // TraditionalForm
```

to get automatically mathematica displayed as
$$\partial_t A$$
instead of
$$ A^{(1,0)}[t,r]$$
However it did not help much.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question itself seems to have nothing to do with [tag:numerics] or [tag:numerical-integration]; maybe [tag:calculus-and-analysis] tho'

Comment: In fact it has to do with the output of PDE system numerical integration. Sometimes it is so chaotic that is useless unless one can manipulate it and convert to an understandable form. And $[t,r]$'s and ${}^{(0,1)}$ are a major source of confusion as far as PDE system numerical integration output it is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

```
pdForm = # /. HoldPattern[Derivative[n__][f_][x__Symbol]] :>
     (Composition @@ 
        Join @@ MapThread[Table[d[#2], {#}] &, {{n}, {x}}])@f &;

Derivative[0, 1][B][t, r] // pdForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Derivative[2, 1][B][t, r] // pdForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This works but depends on specific form of input. Is there a way to simplify output irrespectively of inpute that generates it?

Comment: @user61386 Please show me an example of what you're talking about.